# Horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

*EDIT: I had been misreading where to put the ".HORIZONTAL" for days. After the first two answers posted here, I went back to the examples I'd been using to clarify my understanding of how I'd botched things so badly. Now that I see the correct usage, I cannot make myself see how I ever thought my blinkered code was valid.
Thanks especially to **peprumo** and **learnaholic**.*

I've been fighting with making a RecyclerView scroll horizontally.

All over the place, here and in tutorials, the relevant code gets plunked into MainActivity (or wherever the RecyclerView will be running):

```
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL(this));
```

When I use this code, the LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL gets redlined, and the error says "Cannot resolve symbol 'HORIZONTAL'," despite this being a line that Android Studio suggests.

I found a different bit of code elsewhere, and I tried it instead, and this works:

```
   LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Can anyone explain why the former doesn't work, what that error message means, and why the latter works instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one at the top is trying to create an object of the `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` class, which does not exist.
The second one is creating an object of the `LinearLayoutManager` class and then passing as a second argument the constant `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` which has `0` as a value.

You can check this just by pressing `CTRL + click` (`Command + click` on mac) over the `HORIZONTAL` keyword, you'll see that is defined in the `LinearLayoutManager` class as:

```
public static final int HORIZONTAL = RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL;
```

If you do the same operation over `RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL` you'll see its value in the `RecyclerView` class:

```
public static final int HORIZONTAL = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL;
```

Which is defined inside the `LinearLayout` class as:

```
public static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
```

is a constant, in Java you cannot create a new Object from a constant. that is why the compiler showed your error